# Partial fractions to integrate$\int \frac{4x^2 -20}{(2x+5)^3}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \frac{4x^2 -20}{(2x+5)^3}dx$$

I can't use the coverup method that I learned since making anything zero in this makes everything zero. I would probably just use random test points because I don't have any other tricks memorized. Is there some specific trick I need to use on this so it is possible to compute on a timed test?

Comment: Is there missing a $\,x\,$ squared in the numerator, or is that the new fashion to write $\,16\,$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int \frac{4x^2 -20}{(2x+5)^3}dx = \int \dfrac A{(2x + 5)} + \dfrac B{(2x + 5)^2} + \dfrac C{(2x + 5)^3}\, dx$$

Partial fractions can be thought of as the reverse of "finding the common denominator".

That is, we can equate the numerator of the original integrand with the expansion of each of the numerators of the desired fractions, times the factor we'd need to find the common denominator, if we were adding the fractions in the desired integrand.

Doing this gives us $$A(2x + 5)^2 + B(2x + 5) + C = 4x^2 - 20\tag{1}$$

Solve for C first: to do this we can put $x = -\frac 52$ to zero out all but $$C = 4(-5/2)^2 - 20 = 4\cdot \frac {25}{4} - 20 = 25 - 20 = 5$$

**Then expand the left-hand side**, substitute $C = 5$, and match up coefficients, (you can easily find $A$ that way, since it will be the only term on the left hand side that is a coefficient of a term with $x^2$. Substitute, solve for $B$ knowing $A$. In other situations, you could use two arbitrary values for $x$ to obtain two equations in two unknowns.

Expanding $(1)$: $$A(4x^2 + 20 x + 25) + B(2x + 5) + 5 = 4x^2 - 20 \tag{2}$$ 
$$\implies  4Ax^2 = 4 \implies A = 1$$

Now, we have $A = 1, C = 5$, and can substitute this into our equation $(2)$:

$$4Ax^2 + 20 Ax + 25A + 2Bx + 5B + 5 = 4x^2 - 20$$  $$ \iff (20 A + 2B)x = 0\cdot x $$ $$\iff 20 A + 2B = 0 $$ $$\iff 20\cdot 1 + 2B = 0 \iff B = -10 $$

$$\int \frac{4x^2 -20}{(2x+5)^3}dx = \int \dfrac 1{(2x + 5)} + \dfrac {-10}{(2x + 5)^2} + \dfrac 5{(2x + 5)^3}\, dx$$

Comment: I did this and I run into the problem of getting A+B=4 and A+B = 16

Comment: Why the part of 'expand the left hand side'? Better pass the recently calculated $C$ to the right and divide by $(2x+5)$. Then evaluate again in $-5/2$

Comment: @Franklin There are many ways to do the same thing: throwing too many ways at one time can be counterproductive (and can be nothing more than "showing off"). Better to gradually expose a student first encountering fraction decomposition to new and more novel ways. In any case, it is very clear that the only factor for $x^2$ on the left will be $4A \implies A = 1$. It's not a bad idea to remind the OP about what it means to equate coefficients.

Comment: Although indeterminate coefficients is a powerful general technique in mathematics, in the case of partial fractions is a very bad idea for many reasons: inefficient, confuses the students, requires proficiency solving equations ... Unfortunately it has spread in the classrooms. Mainly because it is easy for teachers to explain. 'Write this and you solve it', is all you need to tell the students. That is why I preach against it. To recover the ancient method of Ruffini. You found $C$ the right way, repeat it for the rest.

Comment: I don't disagree about classroom practices. Don't get me wrong, your post is great for archive purposes, and gives the OP something to refer to when ready to take on the unfamiliar. I just try to balance my desire for educational reform with the needs and readiness of an OP, that's all. The OP has to survive in the context of the "status quo" - and so it's good to help him/her survive, while at the same time, giving them tools to get past the status quo.

Comment: @amWhy: Nice detailed response that uses what the OP is likely learning +1

Comment: $+1\frac{1}{1}$

Comment: Paul - Could you let me know if this has been helpful? I want to be sure you understand. (I am sorry about the other answer above: I know you are trying to learn how to do partial fractions without having to learn stuff that may only be confusing.)

Answer (score 7):

**Ruffini-Horner algorithm + Polynomial long division applied to partial fraction decomposition.**

Because Ruffini-Horner is one of the most efficient methods to evaluate polynomials, this is probably one of the, if not the most efficient methods to compute this and any partial fraction decomposition in general. *Cover up* is a particular case of it, but very incomplete. That is why only learning *cover up* leaves out lots of exercises you will struggle with.

First let me show you the only computations you will need to do. They consist only in writing this table and this table alone.

```
      .   4    0    -20
 -5/2 .      -10     25
 .......................
      .   4  -10    [5]
      .      -10
      ...........
      .  4  [-20]
      .....
      . [4]
```

The numbers in brackets are the ones we were looking for.

CHECK my computations for mistakes afterwards. I often make computational mistakes.

Now I will explain where these numbers are coming from.

**The method.**

The method is based on **Ruffini-Horner algorithm** to evaluate polynomials. This is an algorithm to evaluate a polynomial at a given number. For example, evaluating $4x^2-20$ ar $x=-5/2$ efficiently. It also allows, combined with polynomial long division, for a calculation of any partial fraction decomposition in which the denominator splits completely. By this I mean that it factors completely and all its zeros are reals.

Assume that we have $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ (reduced fraction, i.e. $P$ and $Q$ have no common factors) and $(x-a)^n$ is the highest power of $(x-a)$ that divides $Q$. We want to write $$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{A_1}{(x-a)}+\frac{A_2}{(x-a)^2}+\ldots+\frac{A_n}{(x-a)^n}+h(x),$$

where $h$ doesn't have a pole at $x=a$, i.e. it is the part of the partial fraction decomposition that doesn't have $(x-a)$ in the denominators. Let us multiply both sides by $(x-a)^n$. We get

$$(x-a)^n\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=A_1(x-a)^{n-1}+A_2(x-a)^{n-2}+\ldots+A_n+(x-a)^nh(x),$$

So, computing the coefficients $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ is the same as writing $\frac{(x-a)^nP(x)}{Q(x)}$ as a sum of powers of $(x-a)$.

..........................

**Writing a rational function as a sum of powers of $(x-a)$:**

If we have a rational function $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ and the numerator and denominator are written in decreasing powers of $(x-a)$ then we can write is as a sum of powers of $(x-a)$ (very efficiently) by doing polynomial long division. You can read how this is done in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division). Just remember that here we need to organize the polynomials in decreasing powers of $(x-a)$ instead of ascending powers of $(x-a)$ as the usual long division does. The usual long division proceeds by dividing the terms of highest degree, but here we need to proceed by dividing the terms of lowest degree.

Therefore we only need to see how to (efficiently) write polynomials in powers of $(x-a)$ to complete the algorithm.

..........................

**(re)-Writing polynomials in powers of $(x-a)$:**

This is the part where Ruffini-Horner is used.

Given a polynomial $P(x):=a_nx^n+\ldots+a_0$, say written in powers of $x$. We would like to compute

$$P(x)=A_0+A_1(x-a)+\ldots+A_n(x-a)^n.$$

Notice that $A_0$ is the result of computing $P(a)$. For this computation, one of the most efficient ways is to use [Ruffini-Horner algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method). The cool thing is that Ruffini doesn't only give you $P(a)$, but the partial computations you do give you the result of $(P(x)-A_0)/(x-a)$. It is clear that $$(P(x)-A_0)/(x-a)=A_1+A_2(x-a)+\ldots+A_n(x-a)^{n-1}.$$

Therefore, what we need to do is to apply again Ruffini to this new polynomial, who's coefficients we already have from the previous Ruffini. Repeating $n$ times you get all the $A_i$'s.

..............................

**Summarizing:**

One of *the most efficient ways* to compute the partial fraction decomposition is to first do Ruffini enough times (the number of times corresponds to the degree of the polynomial) with the numerator and the denominator of the given fraction. This will give you the coefficients for writing the numerator and denominator as powers of $(x-a)$. Then do $n$ steps, where $n$ is the power to which $(x-a)$ appears in the denominator, of the long division with these two polynomials to get the coefficients you are looking for. DONE!

..............................

**Your Example:**

I will show you using [Ruffini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method#Examples). First learn how to do Ruffini and the little table used to compute. It is super easy and only involves adding and multiplying a few times. The link to wikipedia shows a short example from where you learn all there is to be learned about how to do Ruffini.

Well, first $(2x+5)^3$ can be written as $8(x+5/2)^3$ and we can forget about the $8$ because it goes outside the integral. So your integral essentially is

$$\int\frac{4x^2-20}{(x+5/2)^3}\text{d}x.$$

Now what we need is to write the numerator $4x^2-20$ in powers of $(x+5/2)$.

For this we use Ruffini. Write the coefficients of the numerator $4$, $0$ and $-20$ and do Ruffini with $-5/2$. Use a table as in the Wikipedia example.

In the Ruffinity table to get $4$, $-10$, $5$. This last number $5$ is the first coefficient of $4x^2-20$ written in powers of $(x+5/2)$, i.e.

$$4x^2-20=5+b(x+5/2)+c(x+5/2)^2.$$

Now, repeat Ruffini with the other numbers you got on the table before $5$, i.e. $4$ and $-10$, using the same evaluation at $-5/2$. We get $4$, and $-20$. This $20$ is the next coefficient, i.e. $b=-20$. Repeat Ruffini with the remaining number $4$, which is like doing nothing. You get $4$, which is the last number $c=4$.

This gives us $$4x^2-20=5-20(x+5/2)+4(x+5/2)^2.$$

Now we divide by the denominator $(x+5/2)^3$ to get $$\frac{4x^2-20}{(x+5/2)^3}=\frac{5}{(x+5/2)^3}+\frac{-20}{(x+5/2)^2}+\frac{4}{(x+5/2)}.$$

When you learn Ruffini you will see that all of this reduces to write down the little table with only $4$ multiplications and $3$ additions at the beginning of the post. I have friends that can do it in their heads.

```
      .   4    0    -20
 -5/2 .      -10     25
 .......................
      .   4  -10    [5]
      .      -10
      ...........
      .  4  [-20]
      .....
      . [4]
```

The numbers in brackets are the ones we were looking for.

.......................

**Comparison with other methods commonly used.**

1. 'Cover up': Only works when the poles are of order $1$. In other words when the exponents of the factors of the denominator are one.
2. Indeterminate coefficients: These are the methods that suggest to multiply, expand and compare coefficients to get system of equations. These waste times in doing those algebraic manipulations, and afterwards you need to solve a system of equations. The system of equations is sometimes large, plus some students are not familiar with solving systems of equations.
3. Other special tricks. These are good, but usually depend on the specific problem and are not applicable in general. For example, the 'cover up' method.

Comment: I read your post before and tried to learn it but I don't know what taylor series is, and in general I was lost trying to read that so I feel like it would take me a lot of time to learn that and time is one thing I don't have. I only have 5 days until the test.

Comment: I am writing a post with what you need to do. The Taylor and stuff is just the explanation of why it works. The explanation can be done with less technical words, though. What you need to do is only what is in the part that says 'Summarizing'.

Comment: It is the fastest method. Teachers don't teach it I don't know why. It is sad that all you see is people doing 'cover up', or systems of equations. I will explain in another answer the arithmetic of this example and you will see.

Comment: Very good answer, can you add an example where you use the theory to find the decomposition of a rational expression?

Comment: I just added an answer computing the example of the question. Maybe I should merge them.

Comment: It is also called Horner method, or Ruffini-Horner algorithm. This name is only the name for the algorithm for evaluating polynomials. This is just how to apply it conveniently to compute partial fraction decomposition. Good to hear there are still places where it is being taught this way.

Comment: If you are answering a question for someone who is in calculus 1 and are going to give them the answer, if you want to provide a bunch of theory, the first thing in your post is exactly how to do their problem.  Then, if they want to read on, they can.  But, making them wade through a bunch of stuff they don't understand is to get to the only part they can understand is not helpful.  I mean no disrespect.  I'm helping you understand how to make this post better.  The very beginning is how to do the problem with this method.  Then, "This method is called... and this is why it works..."

Comment: Got it. It makes a lot of sense. Will change it.

Comment: Actually, now that I read more carefully, this is not what I was taught. I would just set $y=x+5/2$. Then the coefficients will simply appear in the numerator after expansion. In a less trivial case, this requires a division by increasing power.

Comment: That is equivalent. It is the same is going on here. But the key point is that that successive division is what Ruffini does. Each run of Ruffini gives you the coefficients of the quotient and the remainder of that division. It just happens that the remainder is the evaluation of the polynomial in this case. Notice that in more general cases the denominator is not only a power of $(x+5/2)$ so the rest of it must also be written in powers of $(x+5/2)$. Then the long division will be needed.

Comment: @julien I got confused reading your comment. Division by increasing powers is the long division. What I wanted to say is that when you say 'expand' there is when Ruffini enters the picture. How do you expand? One is tempted to open brackets using the binomial coefficients, or worst, multiplying and using associativity. The thing is that Ruffini is the efficient way of doing that 'expand'step.

Comment: Right, that's what I was taught to call Horner. But in most cases, I think it is fair to say that a simple binomial expansion will do the job as efficiently.

Comment: So now that I understand your post (a bit puzzling given that I do know everything you are talking about), I want to reassure you: none of this is getting lost. The computation of the expansion of a rational function with respect to a given pole by long division is how partial fraction decomposition is taught in France (and many other places I'm sure), for instance, together with the usual nice tricks. But we are not told to use Horner when expanding, given that, in the worst case scenario, we are asked to do that for order three poles. On the other hand, we do learn Horner in basic CS.

Comment: In North America all I see is indeterminate coefficients and seas of students failing because they make a mistake either forming or solving a system of equations. It is very unfortunate especially when there is a dumb table that computes those coefficients. I compare it with teaching students to add or divide numbers by using roman numerals, when there is a simple method using decimal notation. (cool thing: I just noticed this analogy goes deeper than just one being harder than the other).

Answer (score 2):

I would use another method, good only when there’s only one linear among the denominators.

Just set $t=2x+5$. so that $x=(t-5)/2$ and $4x^2-20=t^2-10t+5$. Divide this by $t^3$, and you get $5/t^3-10/t^2+1/t$, and now you resubstitute $t=2x+5$ to get your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t realize that @Julien covered this fully in a comment above.

Comment: Well, @julien, I don’t grant that I did a long division, except to put a quadratic polynomial in $t$ all over $t^3$.

Comment: That's not what I meant (and long division is not the right term anyway, I just checked) In this case, it is indeed trivial because there is only one pole. But if, say, $f(x)=\frac{p(x)}{(x-2)^4(x-1)^3}$ and I want the expansion with respect to the pole $1$, I will set $y=x-1$ and do the division of $p(y+1)$ by $(y-1)^4$ by increasing power up to $y^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general outline of how to do this integral. We want to rewrite $$ \frac{4x^2 -20}{(2x+5)^3}$$ as $$\frac{A}{2x+5}+\frac{B}{(2x+5)^2}+\frac{C}{(2x+5)^3},$$
 so we set the two equal and try to find the coefficients, $A,B,C$. To do this we multiply both sides by $(2x+5)^3$ to get
$$A(2x+5)^2+B(2x+5)+C=4x^2-20$$. To do this we will plug $x=-5/2$ into both sides (since that will make $2x+5$ equal to zero). We get $C=4(\frac{-5}{2})^2-20$. Then we differentiate both sides plug $x=-5/2$. This will enable us to solve for $B$. Then we differentiate once more and plug $x=-5/2$ one last time to solve for $A$.